# How to create custom templates for Xamarin Forms solution as SDK project in Visual Studio Mac?

Tags: templates, xamarin.forms, monodevelop, visual-studio-mac

I've tried creating custom template for my Xamarin Forms Solution using the following link https://www.monodevelop.com/developers/articles/creating-a-simple-project-template/

When I run this extension this generates Non SDK format project. How to generate a SDK format project from the .xpt.xml file. Are there any tags to include TargetFramework netstandard2.1 within Project tag? Are there any relevant tags to the SDK project properties like including Nuget packages, grouping projects.

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/the-end-of-monodevelop-80b383dab34b You can no longer apply MonoDevelop knowledge on VS for Mac, as the former is obsolete and updated no more. Ask Microsoft directly and you might get an answer, https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/search?space=41&q=template

Comment: You could take a look at the template creator addin for Visual Studio for Mac. This supports creating project templates from any type of project, SDK or classic - https://lastexitcode.com/blog/2017/11/12/TemplateCreatorForVisualStudioMac/ - with this extension you do not need to build your own extension to provide the project templates - the templates will be available straight away. Also VS Mac supports project templates installed via `dotnet new --install` although you do not have much control over the category - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new-install